# Add app_offline.htm file when completing pull request, and then delete it afterwards once it completes/fails

Tags: git, azure-devops, web-deployment, app-offline.htm

Is it possible for when there is a Pull request being completed, it creates a custom app_offline.htm file, and then removes it once the request completes/fails afterwards?

Been left with a white screen for users when the pull request is being actioned isn't ideal and would like to automate it as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

For this issue , I am afraid it is currently not supported in azure devops. The UI in azure devops are as designed. You also can't add a custom app_offline.htm file to the root directory of azure devops.

If you want an ideal display page , you could add your request for this feature on our [UserVoice site](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21), which is our main forum for product suggestions. Our PM and product team will kindly review your suggestion.

Comment: OK, i've added it to the feature request. Thanks!